# More than 2 partitions using OpenEmbedded's wic kickstart

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

I have a device that requires having 3 partitions on its SD card.  The first and third are the typical boot and rootfs partitions while the second just needs to be blank space.  I'm using the Fido branch of OpenEmbedded oe-core and meta-oe as well as 1.26 of Bitbake.  My kickstart file looks like this:

```
part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4 --size 16
part swap --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --align 4 --size 100
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label root --align 4 --size 2000
```

I use `dd` to write the `.direct` file to my SD card (8 GB) using the `bs=1M` option.  The resulting partition table ends up being corrupt in some way.  I've everything from bad superblocks to incorrect sizes of the partitions and other oddities in gParted like, `cannot initialize '::'`.

If I remove the second partition, everything is fine.  I'm seeing conflicting posts/bug reports indicating that this both is and is not supported.

Has anyone been able to create multiple partitions with wic?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest filing a bug, the maintainer of wic is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the last option:

```
bootloader --ptable msdos
```

or change it according your install